# Read 5.8ghz WIFI data in Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, bridge

I was thinking about to build a Raspberry Pi 5.8Ghz Wifi bridge.

The idea is to add a Wifi USB dongle to the raspberry pi and
send commands from Mobile APP through 5.8Ghz Wifi to the raspberry pi.
The raspberry pi read the commands from Wifi and send some data to another processor through UART.
Has anyone figured out how to read Wifi data in Raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple program in any programming language could solve this. Python , C ,  C++ , Java , C# and Fortran run all on the Pi. Please note that you don't "read WiFi data" but operate on a abstract level : TCP/IP ("sockets") or even more abstract : HTTP.

You **will** need programming knowledge. It is essential , the language itself is not that important ( i *suggest* Python , use anything you're **competent** with).

Comment: Thank you flakeshake.
May I ask what is the different between operate on a TCP/IP layer and HTTP layer? Which one should I choose?

Comment: Which programming language(s) do you know ?

Comment: I know Python.
I guess I will follow your suggestion to use Python.